# Using my code I am returned more than one "smallest is" line or "largest is" line…where are my errors?

Tags: c, integer, comparison

Using:

Book - C How to Program, 7th edition by Paul Deitel, Harvey Deitel

Codeblocks with mingw as compiler

Language - C

Notes:

Arrays and most operands have not yet been introduced thus far in the book. 
Using my code I am returned more than one "smallest is" line or "largest is" line.
I am using this book to teach myself....where are my errors? I am also just starting to learn to code and have chosen C as the language to do this with.

Task:

(Arithmetic, Largest Value and Smallest Value) Write a program that inputs three different
integers from the keyboard, then prints the sum, the average, the product, the smallest and the largest of these numbers. Use only the single-selection form of the if statement you learned in this chapter.

The screen dialogue should appear as follows:

Enter three different integers: 13 27 14

Sum is 54

Average is 18

Product is 4914

Smallest is 13

Largest is 27

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3;

    printf("Please input three integers.");

    scanf("%d%d%d", &num1, &num2, &num3);

    printf("Sum is %d\n", num1 + num2 + num3);
    printf("Average is %d\n", (num1 + num2 + num3) / 3);
    printf("Product is %d\n", num1 * num2 * num3);

    if(num1 > num2 && num3) {
        printf("Largest is %d\n", num1);
    } //end if function
    if(num2 > num1 && num3) {
        printf("Largest is %d\n", num2);
    } //end if function
    if(num3 > num1 && num2) {
        printf("Largest is %d\n", num3);
    } //end if function
    if(num1 < num2 && num3) {
        printf("Smallest is %d\n", num1);
    } //end if function
    if(num2 < num1 && num3) {
        printf("Smallest is %d\n", num2);
    } //end if function
    if(num3 < num1 && num2) {
        printf("Smallest is %d\n", num3);
    } //end if function

}
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: @Jon: The question is: _Using my code I am returned more than one "smallest is" line or "largest is" line…where are my errors?_

Comment: Please note that `if` is not a function; it is a keyword.  You might also care to meditate on what a fixed version of your code would report if the inputs were any of the triads (3, 3, 3), (1, 2, 2), (1, 1, 2).  Also, consider what it would take to extend your code to handle 4 variables instead of 3.  You can quickly see why the alternatives suggested in the two answers are better than your outline.  (This is not to blame you in any way; it is intended to help you think like a programmer. Everyone has to learn the basics at some time.)

Comment: I am open to all information and knowledge. I shall attempt 4 variables and experiment with triads shortly. Very much appreciated and I am definitely at the basics and searching for the best way to learn on my own (with help as needed) until going for a computer science degree. I do indeed wish to adopt the mindset of a programmer and have reviewed everything presented in regards to the question posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition:

```
if(num1 > num2 && num3)
```

means:

```
if (num1 > num2 && num3 != 0)
```

or, equivalently, but with a full set of parentheses:

```
if ((num1 > num2) && (num3 != 0))
```

You need to write:

```
if (num1 > num2 && num1 > num3)
```

Rinse and repeat.

There are better, more compact ways of determining the largest of three integers, such as:

```
int largest = num1;
int smallest = num1;
if (num2 > largest)
    largest = num2;
else if (num2 < smallest)
    smallest = num2;
if (num3 > largest)
    largest = num3;
else if (num3 < smallest)
    smallest = num3;
```

There are also stunts you can pull with the ternary `?:` operator, but you've probably not come across that yet and the stunts don't make for readable code.

Comment: ...and `if (num1 > num2 && num3)` means `if( (num1 > num2) && num3 )`

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Thank you so kindly for pointing out my error and informing me of a more feasible approach to the problem. The code runs as it should with your above instruction.  The ternary ?: is presented in the next chapter. And I have mentally noted readability using stunts.

Comment: To everyone else thank you for your informative input. I shall strive to do more research before asking something that may be simple in nature but complex to my unlearned mind as of yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use functions to do it:

```
int num1, num2, num3;

printf("largest number is %d\n", largest(num1, largest(num2, num3)));
printf("smallest number is %d\n", smallest(num1, smallest(num2, num3)));
```

where `largest(int, int)` and `smallest(int, int)` are:

```
int largest (int a, int b)
{
    if (a > b)
        return a;
    else
        return b;
}
```

and

```
int smallest (int a, int b)
{
    if (a < b)
        return a;
    else
        return b;
}
```